# How to pass objects to angular during bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs

On my main page where angular will be bootstrapped (initially loaded), I will already have an object that my application generates that has user information (isLoggedIn, username, etc.).

I don't see a point of loading angular, and then making an extra API call to get this information.

How can I pass this to angular?

Comment: what do you mean during bootstrap? are you generating before angular bootstrap or on page load?

Comment: Do you have server side code? PHP, ASP.NET, nodejs? If so, you can generate javascript code to inject the values using an angular constant/value.

Comment: @AlexPollan Yes server side code is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp').value('myVariable', myVariable)
```

This will load the object into an injectable static object. Note that you need to call this after you're sure that the object exists and has the correct values.

Also, typically objects that are injected into the `window` object artificially will already be available for angular (however, this is **bad practice**).

So if your variable is set like this:

```
// without var!
myObj = { isLoggedIn: true, username: 'myUser' }
```

or:

```
window.myObj = { isLoggedIn: true, username: 'myUser' }
```

It should be available from `window`. The injection method is preferred, mind you.

Comment: Is there a list of the types of things I can setup somewhere in the docs, like .value .service .provider etc?

Comment: https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/ This is a nice resource, but the angularjs docs are pretty good, you just need to know how to phrase your Google searches :)

Comment: what if the user logs out, or updates their profile and I need to change "myVariable", is that easy to do?  I guess I could just inject it in the e.g. ProfileService right?

Comment: I believe that, since it's with `value` and not `constant`, you can make modifications and they will stick (for the current session at least). If not, you can wrap it as a service or factory which are singletons

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the run() function to do your login actions:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.run(function() { ... })
```

And, if you need to share data between the run function and the controllers, you can to use a service:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.service("myService", function { ... })
.run(function(myService) { ... })
.controller("myController", function(myService) { ... })
```

see full example at [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sakiye/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you have server code then you need to generate angularjs code using the server code. You can use several approaches:

a) If you generate the angularjs page/view using server code then it's very easy to add a javascript block. Example using Razor:

```
@{
    var userContextJsonString = Model.UserContextJsonString;
}

<script>
(function(window){
     window.angularAppModule.value('userContext', @userContextJsonString); 
})(window);
</script>
```

b) If your view/page is static then it's a little trickier. Create a HTTP handler of some kind (page, MVC controller, HTTP handler, etc.) that sends a javascript response to the client with the javascript code generated

In your HTML view/page:

```
<script src="~/jsservergenerator?file=usercontext.js" />
```

and in your HTTP handler (example using ASP.NET handler)

```
public class JsServerGenerator : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       var userContextJsonString = ...;

       context.Response.Write(@"
        (function(window){
          window.angularAppModule.value('userContext', " + userContextJsonString + @"); 
        })(window);");

       //set headers
    }
}
```

(the HTTP handler must be registered in web.config to serve these requests)

Notice that I included non working code, it's only to guide you in your solution.